# Import XML with Lists of Lists in C#

Tags: c#, xml, list, import

I want to import this XML file into C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<YamahaAmplifier>
<Root>
  <RootName>SYS</RootName>
  <UseRoot>YES</UseRoot>
  <Device>
    <DeviceName>MODELNAME</DeviceName>
    <UseFunction>YES</UseFunction>
    <GETCMD>@SYS:MODELNAME=?</GETCMD>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>Character Code: Ascii, Variable Length (1 to 16 characters)</Name>
    </Parameter>
  </Device>
  <Device>
    <DeviceName>SPPATTERN1AMP</DeviceName>
    <UseFunction>YES</UseFunction>
    <PUTCMD>@SYS:SPPATTERN1AMP=</PUTCMD>
    <GETCMD>@SYS:SPPATTERN1AMP=?</GETCMD>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch Normal</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +1ZONE</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>3</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +2ZONE</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>4</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +FRONT</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>5</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +FPR</Name>
    </Parameter>
  </Device>
 </Root>
 <Root>
  <RootName>SYS2</RootName>
  <UseRoot>YES</UseRoot>
  <Device>
    <DeviceName>MODELNAME2</DeviceName>
    <UseFunction>YES</UseFunction>
    <GETCMD>@SYS:MODELNAME=?</GETCMD>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>Character Code: Ascii, Variable Length (1 to 16 characters)</Name>
    </Parameter>
  </Device>
  <Device>
    <DeviceName>SPPATTERN1AMP2</DeviceName>
    <UseFunction>YES</UseFunction>
    <PUTCMD>@SYS:SPPATTERN1AMP=</PUTCMD>
    <GETCMD>@SYS:SPPATTERN1AMP=?</GETCMD>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch Normal</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +1ZONE</Name>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Number>3</Number>
      <Type>SINGLEVAL</Type>
      <Name>7ch +2ZONE</Name>
    </Parameter>
  </Device>
 </Root>
</YamahaAmplifier>
```

I have created these classes to carry it:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("YamahaAmplifier")]
public class YamahaAmplifier
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Root")]
    public List<Root> Roots = new List<Root>();
}

[Serializable()]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("RootName")]
    public string RootName;
    [XmlElement("UseRoot")]
    public string UseRoot;
    [XmlArray("Device")]
    public List<Device> Devices = new List<Device>();
}

[Serializable()]
public class Device
{
    [XmlElement("DeviceName")]
    public string DeviceName;
    [XmlElement("UseFunction")]
    public string UseFunction;
    [XmlElement("GETCMD")]
    public string GETCMD;
    [XmlElement("PUTCMD")]
    public string PUTCMD;
    [XmlArray("Parameter")]
    public List<Parameter> Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
}

[Serializable()]
public class Parameter
{
    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int Number;
    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public string Type;
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;
}
```

And then this code to import to C#:

```
            try
            {
                using (FileStream reader = new FileStream("C:\\Civview\\YNCA_Command_List_RX-A3000_U.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YamahaAmplifier));
                    o = ser.Deserialize(reader) as YamahaAmplifier;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

But I get an error and I just cant get around it, have have been testing a number of solutions to get it to work without sucess.
The error I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an Error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System-MethodAcessException: Attempt by method ´Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderYamahaAmplifier.Read5_YamahaAmplifier(Boolean, Boolean)´ to access method ´HSPI_YAMAHA_RECEIVER.Util+YamahaAmplifier..ctor() failed. 
>      at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderYamahaAmplifier.Read5_YamahaAmplifier(Booleanb isNullable, Boolean checkType)

Any suggestions? A better way of doing it? Anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, your fix works if I create a new project and just enter the code I posted with your changes. But it does not work in my original program. I will have to continue collecting information to describe the problem.

---

Copy pasting it back from the test program made it work with one exception. I had done a misstake in the testprogram typing something like roots.Roots[1].Devices.Count() and that worked there. But when copying back to the original program, I had to remove the () since its not a method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I have imported a nice and neat structure of information that I want to use. One part of my program uses all the information in the structure to create a user interface. Another part of the program must decide what to do if one of the buttons are pressed or the sliers are changed. This latter part gets three pieces of information automatically, I cannot change the code that does this. The information I get is the "RootName", "DeviceName" and "Number" under "Parameter" class.

So what I need to do is to search for the matchin RootName, and under that the matching DeviceName and take that DeviceNames string in "PUTCMD" and add the parameter name which corresponds to the Number I get.

Is there a smart way of doing this? Finding the correct Device under the correct Root and then take the data out of that to creat my transmission string.

Greatful for any help in the correct direction.